# While loop continues even after condition is met (Arduino Nano 33 BLE)

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-c++

Im working with the Arduino Nano 33 BLE using platform.io in VS Code. Im also using the ArduinoBLE library. I created a class which will manage all ble functions for me. One of the first fucntions im working on is this *print_devices(duration)*, which should scan and print found ble advertisement for a certain duration. It works, however for some reason it leaves the loop but then runs again.

main.cpp :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <string>
#include <bg96.hpp>
#include <ble_manager.hpp>

bg96 node = bg96();
ble_manager bluetooth = ble_manager();
uint8_t result = 0;

void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  node.init();
  result = bluetooth.init();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial Started");
}

void loop() {
  //BLE PART

  if (result){
    Serial.println("Failed BLE");
  }
  Serial.println("BLE Started");

  bluetooth.start_scan();
  int scan_time = 5000;
  bluetooth.print_devices(scan_time);
  Serial.println("OWN ADDRESS");
  char add[64];
  bluetooth.get_address(add);

  Serial.println("Delay 5 sec");
  delay(5000);

  //Other bg96 stuff

}
```

function in ble_manager.cpp

```
void ble_manager::print_devices(int duration){
    BLE.scan();
    int starttime = millis();
    int endtime = starttime;
    while ((endtime - starttime) < duration){
        Serial.print("TIME : ");
        Serial.print(endtime - starttime);
        Serial.print(" DURATION : ");
        Serial.println(duration);     
        BLEDevice peripheral = BLE.available();
        if (peripheral) {
            // discovered a peripheral
            Serial.println("Discovered a peripheral");
            Serial.println("-----------------------");

            // print address
            Serial.print("Address: ");
            Serial.println(peripheral.address());

            // print the local name, if present
            if (peripheral.hasLocalName()) {
                Serial.print("Local Name: ");
                Serial.println(peripheral.localName());
            }

            uint8_t advertisement[64] = {0};
            int adLength = peripheral.getAdvertisement(advertisement,64);

            Serial.print("AD length :");
            Serial.println(adLength);

            int hexlen = 0;
            Serial.print("RAW AD :");
            for (int j = 0; j < (adLength); j++) {
                uint8_t thisByte = advertisement[j];
                Serial.print(thisByte,10);
                Serial.print(" ");
                hexlen++;
            }
            
            Serial.println();
            Serial.print("RAW AD :");
            for (int j = 0; j < (adLength); j++) {
                uint8_t thisByte = advertisement[j];
                Serial.print(thisByte, HEX);
                Serial.print(" ");
            }

            Serial.println();
            Serial.print("HEX length :");
            Serial.print(hexlen);

            Serial.println();

            // print the RSSI
            Serial.print("RSSI: ");
            Serial.println(peripheral.rssi());

            Serial.println();
        }
        
        endtime = millis();
    }
    BLE.stopScan();
}
```

output :

```
TIME : 4998 DURATION : 5000
TIME : 4998 DURATION : 5000
TIME : 4999 DURATION : 5000
OWN ADDRESS
4c:45:ee:de:9a:74
TIME : 0 DURATION : 536935700
TIME : 1 DURATION : 536935700
TIME : 1 DURATION : 536935700
TIME : 2 DURATION : 536935700
```

I have no idea how this happens. It seems that it leaves the loop when it prints "OWN ADDRESS", but then it comesback to the while loop and not continuo to delay as it should be. Anyone know whats happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You print `OWN ADDRESS` inside of `loop`, not `ble_manager::print_devices` so you are exiting that function.  That means you most likely have a problem with `bluetooth.get_address(add);` and it is that which is calling `ble_manager::print_devices`

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right, when i removed get_address it doesnt restart. I still dont i understand why tho, but thanks!

Comment: What does `get_address` do?

Comment: You probably call `print_devices` inside `get_address` by mistake.  Look inside `get_address` and check.

Comment: It does this :

uint8_t ble_manager::get_address(char* address){
    String str_address = BLE.address();
    strcpy(address, str_address.c_str());
}

So its very strange, i still trying to get address without causing that while loop error

Comment: How big is `str_address`? Can you guarantee that it can fit into the buffer you're writing to? My guess is you're writing out of bounds which is undefined behavior. You might be overwriting the function return address which causes it to jump back to the wrong place and end up inside your loop.

Comment: I think i can guarantee that, but i will look in to it. I fixed it by changing the function return type, it was uint8_t by i didnt return anything, now its void and the problem is fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not returning a value from a non-void function is also undefined behavior, so that could have caused the problem too.